# Alfresco community edition

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i installed alfresco community edition on GCP virtual machine in linux process is done alfresco is up but  I cannot connect my Alfresco community edition to google drive. how to connect alfresco with google drive?

Comment: When you say you want to "connect alfresco with google drive" what do you mean exactly? Alfresco has its own repository and content store. Are you trying to sync documents from Google Drive into the Alfresco repository? Or do you want to browse a folder in Alfresco and somehow see documents that reside in Google Drive? It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Every request your application sends to the Drive API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

Please follow the [link](https://github.com/Alfresco/googledrive) to know better about the google drive integration.

Comment: The documentation in the link(github link| README) corresponds to google docs, but we need to connect alfresco with Google Drive. Can you guide us in this aspect. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't come across any API which would readily integrate Google Drive and Alfresco. So, this approach seems to be a development from scratch.